# What does "Is /clock being published?" error means?

Tags: ros, tabletop-object-detector, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to test the function of tabletop_segmentation.But when my node send a service request to /tabletop_segmentation, I always get messages indicate that "NO_CLOUD_RECEIVED".

```
[ INFO] [1355922807.919213857, 1093.482000000]: Tabletop detection service called; waiting for a point_cloud2 on topic /narrow_stereo_textured/points2
[ERROR] [1355922813.224946787, 1096.538000000]: Tabletop object detector: no point_cloud2 has been received
```

The problem is /tabletop_segmentation node receive no data from /narrow_stereo_textured/points2.(This topic exists, though)

To test /narrow_stereo_textured/points2, I started gazebo by

```
  roslaunch manipulation_worlds pr2_table_object.launch
```

And I use rviz to see what /narrow_stereo_textured/points2 published, and I can see the content by changing Fixed frame from /map to /head_mount_kinect_ir_frame.

[image: image description]

However, when I try to rostopic echo this topic, I got

```
rosfuerte@rosfuerte-K53SM:~/project/nlp/libsvm-3.14$ rostopic echo /narrow_stereo_textured/points2
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
```

And the segmentation fails as usual, does anyone know how to solve this problem? I want to test the function of segmentation alone. Thanks.

EDIT:
This problem doesn't occur on another computer, which is also fuerte on ubuntu 12.04. I tried sudo apt-get dist-upgrade but I still got the error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50805/what-does-%22is-/clock-being-published?%22-error-means?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-12-26**:
Are you adding the time to the message header on publication?

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-12-28**:
This topic is published by Gazebo, I am not sure if I should modify the message header~

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2013-11-13**:
Are you playing data back from a bag file? Something set use_sim_time to true on the parameter server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If simulated time is active, you should usually play back bags with the --clock option...

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2